# Java int=1 transformed into long=2

Tags: java, junit

I'm writting JUnit test and I have a line like this used several times

```
Assert.assertEquals("Size of list is incorrect", 1, list.size());
```

As some places, this line works fine but something the Java conversion fails.

Method signature is

> void org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(String message, long expected, long
>   actual)

At some point it fails because `list.size()` is an `int=1` but once past to `assertEquals(String message, long expected, long actual)` is becames a `long=2` and assertion is failing.

Putting explicit casting like `Integer.valueOf()` or `Long.valueOf` solve the issue but why the JVM is changing the value at line 60 (while and at line 30 it works as attended) ?

Comment: There is no way `(int) 1` is being turning into `(long) 2L` If it appears to be `2` as a `long` it was `2` as an `int`.

Comment: "the value at line 60 (while and at line 30 it works as attended) " which lines are you talking about.  Did you do anything between these lines which might be the cause of the problem.  I suggest you use a debugger to get a better understanding of what you program is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging with teamate, it seems that the eclipse fails at some point to recompile the class and code was using an other variable from a previous copy/paste.

Comment: That is what unit tests are for: checking that eclipse compiles correctly. ;)